# Unit test of custom snackbar with dismiss action

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have defined many different methods to open a customs snackbar with and without duration and with and without dismiss event, for example:

```js
showError(title: string, message: string): void {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.snackBar.openFromComponent(NotificationSnackbarComponent, {
        duration: 3000,
        data: {
          title,
          message,
          snackType: 'error',
          closeSnackbar: () => {
            this.snackBar.dismiss();
          },
        },
      });
    });
  }
```

How can I made a unit test for this event:

```js
closeSnackbar: () => {   this.snackBar.dismiss(); },
```

I tried with this aproach:

```js
it('should show notification smackbar from showError', () => {
    const spy = spyOn(snackBar, 'openFromComponent');
    const snackBarSpy = spyOn(snackBar, 'dismiss');
    service.showError('Title', 'Message');
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    snackBar.dismiss();
    expect(snackBarSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
  });
```

but I need to test `closeSnackbar` instead of `dismiss`. I don't know how could I get access to that method. I have this beforeEach config:

```js
let service: NotificationService;
let snackBar: MatSnackBar;

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MatSnackBarModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: MatSnackBarRef, useValue: {} },
        { provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, useValue: {} },
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(NotificationService);
    snackBar = TestBed.inject(MatSnackBar);
});
```

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below, I have added comments. Hopefully you can follow along and understand.

```js
let service: NotificationService;
  let snackBar: MatSnackBar;
  let mockSnackBarRef: jasmine.SpyObj<MatSnackBarRef>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // the first string ('SnackBarRef') is used for debugging purposes
    // the second array of strings are public methods you would like to mock
    mockSnackBarRef = jasmine.createSpyObj<MatSnackBarRef>('SnackBarRef', ['openFromComponent', 'dismiss']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MatSnackBarModule
      ],
      providers: [
        // change it to provide the mock - I assume this.snackBar is
        // MatSnackBarRef
        { provide: MatSnackBarRef, useValue: mockSnackBarRef },
        { provide: MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA, useValue: {} },
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(NotificationService);
    snackBar = TestBed.inject(MatSnackBar);
  });

....
it('should show notification smackbar from showError', () => {
    service.showError('Title', 'Message');
    // expect method to be called
    expect(mockSnackBarRef.openFromComponent).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // get the 2nd argument of the most recent call of openFromComponent
    const secondArgument = mockSnackBarRef.openFromComponent.calls.mostRecent().args[1];
    // call the closeSnackbar
    secondArgument.data.closeSnackbar();
    // expect the dismiss to be called
    expect(mockSnackBarRef.dismiss).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I'm getting this error with your example: Generic type 'MatSnackBarRef<T>' requires 1 type argument(s) I don't know very well how does the mocks works. any idea about what can be necesary?

Comment: If i add my snackbar custom component (If I'm understabdibng) like: let mockSnackBarRef: jasmine.SpyObj<NotificationSnackbarComponent>;  I have an error on mockSnackBarRef like: let mockSnackBarRef: jasmine.SpyObj<NotificationSnackbarComponent>; Maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: So it seems `MatSnackBarRef` accepts a generic (T) and I think the generic of type `T` describes the shape of `data` in `openFromComponent`. Try putting `MatSnackBarRef<any>` everywhere where it is required. `any` means it can be anything `object, array, string, number, boolean, custom data type`.

Comment: thanks again, using that way get this error: Property 'openFromComponent' does not exist on type 'SpyObj<MatSnackBarRef<any>>'

Comment: You can try `jasmine.SpyObj<any>` instead. I am not quite sure. I don't have much experience with Angular Material (I assume this is Angular Material).

Comment: with any, it doesn't show errors on visual studio code, but when I run the test I have the error:   "TypeError: Cannot read property 'openFromComponent' of undefined" and the click statement still be uncovered

Comment: and yes sorry, this is a smackbar from material

Comment: Can you show the `constructor` of the component? I am wondering what `this.snackbar` is.

Comment: of course this is "constructor(@Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any) {}"

Comment: So what is `this.snackbar`? Is it a reference to the the snackbar component in the HTML? And if it is a component in the html and you're getting `cannot read property `openFromComponent` of undefined`, it most likely means that the component is not painted in the HTML at that point in time. It could be blocked with an *ngIf or something like this.

Comment: So maybe a timming question? ok let me see if I caught posibility. Thanks